# Issues with async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await for a very basic promise, but I'm getting the error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. However, I believe I'm using await for an async function.

```
function getNumber(mult) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(10);
    }).then((val) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(val * mult)
            //reject("Error");
        }).then((val2) => val2);
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    })
}

const calculate = async (x) => await Promise.resolve(getNumber(x))
const val = await calculate(2)
```

Comment: `const val = await calculate(2)` must be in an async function.

Comment: There's a lot of superfluous code here, in addition to the problem that your `await calculate` isn't in an async function as the error explains. `calculate` could be simply `getNumber(x)` as the extra `async`/`await` and `Promise.resolve` don't do anything, the many `new Promises` and `then`s seem pointless. I'm not sure I understand what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: Why are you using promises in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the initial function with an `await` at the top level...  just a modification.

```js
function getNumber(mult) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(10);
    }).then((val) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(val * mult)
            //reject("Error");
        }).then((val2) => val2);
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    })
}

const calculate = (x) => Promise.resolve(getNumber(x));

const val = calculate(2).then(resp => {
    console.log('do something with response: ', resp)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To only focus on why you're getting that error, the `await` in `await calculate(2)` isn't in an asynchronous function. If you can make it asynchronous function then do that but if not then you can use the `.then()` function like below:

```
calculate(2).then(val => {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: The fix is correct but I think the reason is wrong. The error isn’t due to `calculate` not being an async function. I'm pretty sure you can await any value

Comment: This will of course mean that `val` is now a promise that resolves to a number, instead of simply being a number. So you may also need to change the code that calls this function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, you can await any value, and if it's not a promise it will be converted to one. The problem is that you can only use `await` inside an `async` function.

Comment: That’s correct @evolutionxbox however the issue is that the `calculate` function and the `await` keyword isn’t **inside** an asynchronous function

Comment: Ah, good catch @David Knipe. I’ve edited my answer to a more complete solution that allows you to use the returned value. Thanks!